# How can I support my backend multiple range request while downloading video from aws s3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, video, download

I have to perform a request to my backend from a client to download video preview and those are in s3 server. The request fetch the video from s3 and send back to client. For large video file it took much time. So I need to perform range request. Single range request works well and send me exact bytes of data. But when I add multiple range request it does not send that chunked data. Is there a process to do that?

Single range request works well and send me exact bytes of data. But when I add multiple range request it does not send that chunked data. Is there a process to do that?

NB: S3 doesn't support multiple range request. So I am sending request to s3 with only one range and getting that stream of bytes and sending that to client. But it only sending first byte range.

```
public multiPartRangeRequest() {
  val boundaryString = MimeTypeUtils.generateMultipartBoundaryString();
    response.setContentType("multipart/byteranges; boundary=" + boundaryString);

    val out = response.getOutputStream();

    for (val range : ranges) {
      val length = objectMeta.getContentLength();
      val start = range.getRangeStart(length);
      val end = range.getRangeEnd(length);
      val rangeLength = end - start + 1;

      val inputStreamFromS3 = s3Manager.getObject(fileId, fileType, length, range)
          .getObjectContent();
      out.println();
      out.println("--" + boundaryString);
      response.setHeader(CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(rangeLength));
      response.setHeader(CONTENT_RANGE, "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + length);
      IOUtils.copy(inputStreamFromS3, response.getOutputStream());
      out.println(CONTENT_RANGE + ": bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + length);
      out.println(CONTENT_LENGTH + ": " + rangeLength);

    }
}
```

Comment: I got the solution. The problem was setting the header in response.